# jQuery AJAX - Make content appear by default

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic, default

I'm using jQuery AJAX to retrieve a page with different user selected options. I'd like the page to appear by default with default options so in $(document).ready I call the function which contains the AJAX.

This creates a delay in loading as the browser first loads the actual page, then the jQuery javascript file and then finally it requests the other page.

How can I have the content already appear by default - is there something I can do server side (classic ASP)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are putting the content inside a Div let's say...

```
<div id="my_dynamic_content">This is the default content, just put it here from server side code</div>
```

in your js code

```
$("#my_dynamic_content").html( data );
```

This way is the way I am providing alternate content for flash as well, I just put some content in the DIV and the replacing it in JS code.

Comment: Thanks, thought so. From the server side, either get the content by simulating an AJAX call by POSTing data with ServerXMLHTTP, or put the code in the page I'm calling into a Subroutine and change the page I call to just call the Subroutine and then I can call the Subroutine for the default view.